# Python: PowerShell command-line arguments parser

Tags: python, powershell, argparse

I wonder if there is an open-source Python project to parse PowerShell command-line arguments?

I know that Python has built-in module `argparse` which is able to parse command-line arguments, but with PowerShell arguments:

- Partial/incomplete arguments are still valid
- Case insensitive

For example, on Windows console, these are all valid:

```
> powershell.exe -Command "[console]::WriteLine(\"Hello\")"
Hello
> powershell.exe -Comman "[console]::WriteLine(\"Hello\")"
Hello
> powershell.exe -cOMm "[console]::WriteLine(\"Hello\")"
Hello
> powershell.exe -c "[console]::WriteLine(\"Hello\")"
Hello
```

Alternatively, if there appears no open-source project to achieve this parsing, what would you recommend?

Comment: Why would you ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  But `argparse` does accept abbreviations for flags (in recent versions you can turn that off).  It is case sensitive, but you could tweak the `sys.argv` list beforehand to lower case all flags.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, I understand that argparse does accept abbreviations for flags, e.g. add_argument('-Command', '-c', ...), but I wonder with something with PowerShell-like syntax (which accepts all combinations of abbreviations), that I would have to specify them one by one, which to me more like hard-coded solution.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I guess my question was already clear enough. I was trying to look for a Python solution to parse PowerShell-like command line arguments which support not only its shortest abbreviation, but also all combinations of the command's abbreviations. Your insights / suggestions are definitely more than welcome.

Comment: @hpaulj interesting, I completely missed the explanation about abbreviations, apparently it is there as explained in section 15.4.4.4 from https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching. Thank you for your pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
parser.add_argument('-c','--command');
parser.add_argument('-domain');
```

'-c','--command', '--com' etc all work.  '-com' does not.

'-domain', '-d', '--dom' also work.

```
parser.add_argument('-c','-command')
```

gives some problems, since there's an ambiguity between the two single dash flags.

The ideal, for `argparse` (based on POSIX standards) is to use a single dash and character short flag, and a double dash long.

Short flags can be chained; while long ones allow '='`.  A '-long' falls in a crack between the two; it works, but not as predictably.

Comment: actually for my use case, `parser.add_argument('-command')` can cover _command_, _comman_, ..., _c_. However, the case sensitivity remains an issue, as there is no built-in `argparse` flag to toggle it. So I guess I'd have to manually tweak the `argv` as you suggested in previous comment.